# Voltages from thermistors drop at the input of op-amps in follower configuration

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, operational-amplifier, pcb-design, adc

I designed a PCB to monitor temperature, pressure, voltage, and current. To monitor the temperature I am using thermistors conditioned with a voltage divider. The output of the divider goes to the input of an op-amp in follower configuration, the package is 2 op-amps, the output of the op-amps goes to a multiplexer, and the multiplexer to the ADC of a microcontroller.

I have a problem with the output voltages of the op-amps. When soldering an op-amp to the board and connecting fixed voltages to the inputs of the op-amps simulating the voltages of the thermistors, the op-amp works fine, but if I solder another op-amp to the board and I connect fixed voltages, on one side of both op-amps the voltage drops at the output, the voltages drop from 600 mV.

The input voltages of the op-amps have a maximum of 3.3 V, which is the supply voltage that the thermistors in the voltage divider will have. I've already checked the power supplies and the continuities in the circuit and I can't find the reason why the voltage drops.

The thermistor leads are soldered to a DB25. The thermistor conditioning circuit is a voltage divider with a 3.9 kΩ resistor. The thermistor is located at the top of the divider, powered by a voltage of 3.3 V.

I add the screenshots of the schematics showing the connection of the thermistors, the connection of the output of the multiplexers to a microcontroller, and a 3D view of the connection of the op-amps.

Could you give me some suggestions?

[image: Thermistor]

[image: microcontroller]

[image: 3D]

Comment: ![thermistors](https://1drv.ms/i/s!Aj5B95ZtZ-55gmvW_sjOsFnlccRF?e=fS1svI)
![microcontroller](https://1drv.ms/i/s!Aj5B95ZtZ-55gmxXgWcB6s2Ut3HW?e=0jzDh3) 
![3D](https://1drv.ms/i/s!Aj5B95ZtZ-55gm2sPN83gM9JmeL4?e=2H9Mmr)

Comment: Is that "thermistor" schematic complete and up-to-date? The op-amp outputs don't appear to go anywhere but on the PCB they obviously do.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Hello, thanks for your reply, I apologize, I already uploaded the correct image in the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have thermistor high-side connected to general 3V3 from which at least multiplexers are powered, possibly also your MCU.

Good thinking of converting low side impedance using followers, but your reference voltage on top is noisy, as MCU switches signals/captures ADC, etc. This generates voltage drops all across the PSU. This I'm saying from experience, although I wasn't even buffering my setup :)

To verify - try scoping 3V3 near thermistor and correlate with output from opamp. Or just try powering thermistors from a separate stable supply.

To rectify, either:

- provide separate thermistor supply or
- provide local power filtering - put a small resistor (10-100R) in series with thermistor supply and bypass that with a cap. You might have to wait for cap to fully charge up (RC constant), before getting correct measurements.

You could also provide same sort of filtering for opamps or any other analog circuitry